# How to delete or hide edit UIButton for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I add edit UIButton to UITableViewController

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

But I can't to find method for delete or hide it, just disabled

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the navigation's `leftbarButtonItem` by

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

and again set it by your method

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```